# \pstSetAbsoluteOrigin Adds Space Before Section

Tags: spacing, pstricks, pst-abspos

As soon as I execute `\pstSetAbsoluteOrigin` a space is been added before the section. Is this normal, am I doing something wrong?

I would expect the position of the first section no to be influenced by `\pstSetAbsoluteOrigin` if you add text in front of the section everything behaves as expected. `\pstSetAbsoluteOrigin` seams to add an invisible line of text.

**The expected behavior**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[absolute]{pst-abspos} 

\begin{document}
% \pstSetAbsoluteOrigin
\section{}

\end{document}
```

**The strange behavior**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[absolute]{pst-abspos} 

\begin{document}
\pstSetAbsoluteOrigin
\section{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it this way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[absolute]{pst-abspos}     
\begin{document}

\section{one}
\pstPutAbs(5,-5){Hi}
\newpage
\section{two}
\pstPutAbs(6,-5){Hi}

\end{document}
```

With `[absolute]` it is internally already set at the beginning of the first page. And with `\newpage` it is set on the following page.